# Recursion function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is the problem:

Write a recursive function f that generates the sequence `0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875`. The first two terms are 0 and 1, every other term is the average of the two previous.

```
>>> f(0)
0
>>> f(1)
1
>>> f(2)
0.5
>>> [(i,f(i)) for i in range(10)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.75), (4, 0.625), (5, 0.6875), (6, 0.65625), (7, 0.671875), (8, 0.6640625), (9, 0.66796875)]
```

This is my code so far, I can't seem to figure it out. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
def f(n):
  if n==0:
    return 0
  if n==1:
    return 1
  else:
    return f(n-2)//f(n-1)
```

Comment: `return f(n-2)//f(n-1)`?? Is that the way to calculate an average?

Comment: Please indent your code properly (indent everything, not just the first line).

Comment: Also, please refrain from editing the code that is causing the problem based on the answers you are given (except cosmetically).

Answer (score 3):

The recursive case is wrong:

```
return f(n-2)//f(n-1) # not the formula for the average of two numbers
```

The average of two numbers *a* and *b* is *(a+b)/2*. So  you can define your function as:

```
def f(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (f(n-1)+f(n-2))/2
```

Or we can make it Python version-independent like:

```
def f(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0.5*(f(n-1)+f(n-2))
```

You can then generate the sequence with list comprehension like:

```
>>> [f(i) for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

or by using a `map`:

```
>>> list(map(f,range(10)))
[0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

Comment: Using 2.0 instead of 2 (in the division) will ensure that it also works in python 2.X

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: yeah. But multiplying by `0.5` is in my opinion even better since multiplication is usually carried out faster than division on a FPU (iirc divsion is done by first inverting the second operand and then perform multiplication).

Comment: This does not generate a sequence, just computes the `nth` term.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yeah but based on the code provided by the OP I had the impression that that was not the missing point. The code demonstrates list comprehension to generate such sequence.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem not sure how "smart" python is, but dividing by two will probably be executed as a bit shift, so it will actually be super fast.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki. The issue is that the `/` operator does very different things in Python 2 and Python 3. Also, division by 2 is only a bit shift for integers, and this question is definitely not about integers.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: with floating point numbers division by two is not a bitshift, it is a decrement on the exponent. But afaik most FPUs won't offer a special command for that. Furthermore from what I've always heard, Python does between close to nothing and nothing on the side of optimization. Code is almost evaluated as you write it (Python is also an interpreted language, so there is not much time to evaluate anyway).

Comment: *"multiplying by 0.5 is in my opinion even better since multiplication is usually carried out faster than division"* but then you use tree recursion `f(n-1)+f(n-2)`? Tree recursive `f(40)` takes over **1 minute** but *linear iterative* recursion `f(40)` in less than 1 ms – I know, I know, the question isn't about optimising the performance of the function, but we simply cannot talk about multiplication vs division if we're not first addressing tree vs linear recursion...

Comment: @naomik: no the question explicitly asks for a recursive way. Of course it is not a good idea to do this with recursion, since it results in *dramatic* branching...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this opens the talking point of recursive *procedure* vs recursive *process*, but it probably deserves an exploration better than we could achieve in comments. Can I direct your attention towards my answer?   How would you classify that implementation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've crossed paths with you many times on the site and I respect your contributions here; I hope it goes without saying that my intentions/motivations are purely constructive.

Answer (score 2):

So you have `U0 = 0`, `U1 = 1`, and `Un = (U(n-1) + U(n-2)) / 2` for `n > 1`.

You just have to literally translate this as a function:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (f(n-1) + f(n-2)) / 2
```

Now for generating the sequence of the `Ui` from `0` to `n`:

```
def generate_sequence(n):
    return [f(i) for i in range(n)]
```

This could (and really should) be optimized with memoization. Basically, you just have to store the previously computed results in a dictionary (while you could directly use a list instead in this case).

```
results = dict()
def memoized_f(n):
    if n in results:
        return results[n]
    else:
        results[n] = f(n)
        return results[n]
```

This way, `f(n)` will be computed only once for each `n`.

As a bonus, when `memoized_f(n)` is called, the `results` dictionary holds the values of `f(i)` from `0` to *at least* `n`.

Comment: The final solution is not recursive. Why not just append to the list as you go?

Comment: I would use an array (where the key is the index) to allow the user to print out the sequence immediately without having to sort it. Either way, nice work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's right. I find it more practical to have a basic function that generates the result for one single value at a time, and then generate what I need. However, when memoizing with a list, the said list holds the sequence of the values up to at least the given parameter.

Comment: You are absolutely right to do it that way. I would do the same. Just nitpicking based on OP's stated requirements :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's still a pretty good comment, because sometimes, nothing more than the requirement should be made, especially on hardware with limited storage. Which is generally not the case with Python, though :)

Comment: I went ahead and posted a sample of local memoization that only remembers the current sequence for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

**Recursion à la auxiliary function**

You can define this using a simple auxiliary procedure and a couple state variables – the following `f` implementation evolves a *linear iterative* process

```
def f (n):
  def aux (n, a, b):
    if n == 0:
      return a
    else:
      return aux (n - 1, b, 0.5 * (a + b))
  return aux(n, 0, 1)

print([f(x) for x in range(10)])
# [0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

---

**Going generic**

Or you can genericize the entire process in what I'll call `fibx`

```
from functools import reduce

def fibx (op, seed, n):
  [x,*xs] = seed
  if n == 0:
    return x
  else:
    return fibx(op, xs + [reduce(op, xs, x)], n - 1)
```

Now we could implement (eg) `fib` using `fibx`

```
from operator import add

def fib (n):
  return fibx (add, [0,1], n)

print([fib(x) for x in range(10)])
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Or we can implement your `f` using `fibx` and a custom operator

```
def f (n):
  return fibx (lambda a,b: 0.5 * (a + b), [0, 1], n)

print([f(x) for x in range(10)])
# [0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

---

**Wasted computations**

Some answers here are recursing with (eg) `0.5 * (f(n-1) + f(n-2))` which duplicates heaps of work. `n` values around 40 take astronomically longer (*minutes* compared to *milliseconds*) to compute than the methods I've described here.

Look at the tree recursion `fib(5)` in this example: see how `fib(3)` and `fib(2)` are repeated several times? This is owed to a naïve implementation of the `fib` program. In this particular case, we can easily avoid this duplicated work using the auxiliary looping function (as demonstrated in my answer) or using memoisation (described in another answer)

Tree recursion like this results in O(n<sup>2</sup>), whereas linear iterative recursion in my answer is O(n)

[image: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node13.html]

---

**Generating a sequence for `n`**

Another answer provided by @MadPhysicist generates a sequence for a single `n` input value – ie, `f(9)` will generate a list of the first 10 values. However, the implementation is simultaneously complex and naïve and wastes heaps of computations due to the same `f(n-1), and`f(n-2)` calls.

A *tiny* variation on our initial approach can generate the same sequence in a fraction of the time – `f(40)` using my code will take a fraction of a second whereas these bad tree recursion answers would take upwards of **2 minutes**

(Changes in **bold**)

```
def f (n):
  def aux (n, acc, a, b):
    if n == 0:
      return acc + [a]
    else:
      return aux (n - 1, acc + [a], b, 0.5 * (a + b))
  return aux(n, [], 0, 1)

print(f(9))
# [0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that generates your sequence in a single call, without having to call the function for each element of the list, you can store the values you compute as you unwind the stack:

```
def f(n, _sequence=None):
    if _sequence is None:
        _sequence = [0] * (n + 1)
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        val = n
    else:
        f(n - 1, _sequence)
        f(n - 2, _sequence)
        val = 0.5 * (_sequence[n - 1] + _sequence[n - 2])
    _sequence[n] = val
    return _sequence
```

This has the advantage of not requiring multiple recursions over the same values as you would end up doing with `[f(n) for n in range(...)]` if `f` returned a single value.

You can use a more global form of memoization as suggested by @RightLeg to record the knowledge between multiple calls.

Unlike the other solutions, this function will actually generate the complete sequence as it goes. E.g., your original example would be:

```
>>> f(9)
[0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.625, 0.6875, 0.65625, 0.671875, 0.6640625, 0.66796875]
```

Comment: You're returning `[None, 1]` on `1`. I think you'd better return a static result when given `0` or `1`, namely: `if n == 0: return [0] elif n == 1: return [0, 1]`, or something like `if n in (0, 1): return [0, 1][:n+1]` (which is IMO unnecessarily complicated). +1 for the idea though

Comment: @Rightleg. Problem solved. Initializing to `[0] * (n+1)` instead of `[None] * (n+1)`. There was no good reason to use `None` besides just habit.

Comment: Tree recursion used in this answer wastes heaps of computations – `f(40)` takes almost **2 minutes**. Other things like leaked private api, single-branch `if` statements, mutation/reassignments, and function side-effects feel very clumsy and awkward when using recursion (which has its roots in functional programming)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution might look like this:

```
a=0.0
b=1.0
count = 0
def f(newavg, second, count):

    avg = (second+newavg)/2
    print avg

    count=count+1
    if count<8:
        newavg = avg
        f(second, avg, count)
f(a, b, count)
```

Granted this code just outputs to the monitor...if you want the output into a list just add the code in the recursion.

Also be careful to properly indent where required.